How to connect to MariaDB if DBeaver returns Bad Auth plugin error
DBeaver can't connect to MariaDB
Via MariaDB driver:
Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server. plugin type was = ''

Via MySQL driver:
!AuthenticationProvider.BadAuthenticationPlugin!

When using the terminal everything is ok
~:$ mysql testdb -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor....

When using phpMyAdmin, everything is ok as well.
